# accessing a python object list from javascript

Tags: javascript, python, json, flask

I am using flask and python to build a web application.
I have a json parsable class in python

```
class uItem:
   itemCount = 0

   def __init__(self, id, name):
      self.id = id
      self.name = name
```

I need to access an array a list of objects of this class from html

this is where i create the object and make them json parsable

```
from delClass import uItem

counter = 0
name = ["proudct1","product2","product3"]
objarray = []

for n in name:
    obj = uItem(counter, n)
    r = json.dumps(obj.__dict__)
    counter = counter + 1
    objarray.append(r)
```

This is where i load the index page

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def main():
    return render_template('jsex.html', dlist=objarray)
```

I get an error saying

> **Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list**

[image: Thisis the error that i am getting]
how do i fix this.
is ther a better way to access python lists from javascript ?

Comment: Could you please add a full screenshot of the error window?

Comment: i added a screenshot of the full error

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, this line is the root cause

```
var counts = JSON.parse("["{\"id\": 0, \"name\": \"product1\"}", "{\"id\": 1, \"name\": \"product2\"}", "{\"id\": 2, \"name\": \"product3\"}"]");
```

---

To solving this issue, using `flask.jsonify`.

```
from flask import jsonify

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def main():
    return jsonify(objarray)
```

The json return would be like this:

```
[
  "{\"name\": \"proudct1\", \"id\": 0}",
  "{\"name\": \"product2\", \"id\": 1}",
  "{\"name\": \"product3\", \"id\": 2}"
]
```

After using `jsonify`, you don't need to use `JSON.parse` anymore. The result of both Ajax get/post will be a javascript object. Here is an example code of javascript in nodejs.

```
var axios = require('axios');
axios.get('http://localhost:5000').then(function(res){
    var data = res.data;
    console.log(data);
    console.log(typeof(data));
    console.log(data[0]); 
})
```

The result on the screen:

```
[ '{"id": 0, "name": "proudct1"}',
  '{"id": 1, "name": "product2"}',
  '{"id": 2, "name": "product3"}' ]
object
{"id": 0, "name": "proudct1"}
```